# How to reverse a firebase list with javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to reverse the order of a list of Firebase objects

I tried with "insertBefore", "insertAdjacentHTML", "reverse()" but I do not have the expected result (unordered or white screen)...

Would have you an idea?

Thank you!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Classement TOP 10</title>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
     (function(){
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com"
  };
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var userDataRef = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByChild('points').limitToLast(10);

userDataRef.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var firstName_val = childSnapshot.val().firstName;
         // console.log(firstName_val);
      var lastName_val = childSnapshot.val().lastName.substr(0,1);
         // console.log(lastName_val);
      var points_val = childSnapshot.val().points;
         // console.log(points_val);

      var x = document.createElement("li");
      var t = document.createTextNode(firstName_val + " " + lastName_val + ". - " + points_val + " points");
      x.appendChild(t);
      document.getElementById("classement").appendChild(x);

  });
 });
}());
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <ol id="classement"></ol>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `I tried with "insertBefore", "insertAdjacentHTML"` where? show it, we can tell you how you did it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using insertBefore:

```
.then(function(snapshot) {
    var tgt = document.getElementById("classement");
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        /// ...
        tgt.insertBefore(x, tgt.firstChild);
    });
```

or, turn snapshot into a real array, using this:

```
const snapshotToArray = snapshot => {
    const ret = [];
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        ret.push(childSnapshot);
    });
    return ret;
};
```

*(As I'm not familiar enough with firebase, the above may be overkill, if snapshot is iterable, then you may not need the above function, it may be a case of Array.from(snapshot) to create an array from snapshot)*

in your code, use it like:

```
.then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshotToArray(snapshot).reverse().forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        // your code unchanged
    })
})
```

Comment: Your first option (insertBefore) seems to work ! :-)

Comment: Your solution with insertBefore